# How to display a Map inside a field of a specific document in firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[This is the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpiRS.png) Hello, how to retrieve a map from firestore which is inside a field of a specific document and how to display it as a list in the app. How can be this achieved? Can someone please share a example snippet of code. Like for example in "Collection-Doc-Field-{key : value}" i want to display the map which is in the Field.

Updated :

```
Expanded(
                child: new ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .get('$field')
                      .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    return new ListTile(
                        title: Column(
                            children: (document.data()['$field']
                                    as Map<String, dynamic>)
                                .entries
                                .map((e) => ListTile(
                                    title: Text(e.key),
                                    trailing: Text(e.value.toString())))
                                .toList())
                        //subtitle: new Text(document.data()['Subjects']),
                        );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
```

This is how im trying to display the Map of field, but ending up with this error

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#d3cf2):
type '(DocumentSnapshot) => ListTile' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `snapshot.data` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) object. So, when you call `.get(field)`, it returns a `Map<String, dynamic>` object based on your database structure.
When you write `.map(DocumentSnapshot document)`, you're using the wrong type as it is meant to map through the items in the `Map<String, dynamic>` which is not of type `DocumentSnapshot`.

**Solution**

You need to cast the result of your `get('$field')` [which can be simplified to `get(field)`] to the type of object you're expecting [in this case, it is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`] and then you loop through each map entry to return a `ListTile` widget.

Update your code to the one below and that should fix the error:

```dart
     return ListView(
       children:
         (snapshot.data.get(field) as Map<String, dynamic>)
           .entries
           .map((MapEntry mapEntry) {
             return ListTile(
               title: Text(mapEntry.key),
               trailing: Text(mapEntry.value.toString()));
       }).toList(),
     );
```

Comment: Great! It worked.But Victor can you please tell me what was the main problem in my code.Why using map instead of MapEntry resulted in that exception?

Comment: Hi, @Learn, I've updated my answer with the explanation. Let me know if you need some more explanation.